# Pyinstaller: OSError: Cannot load AutoItX from path

Tags: python, pyinstaller, autoit

So I have a program and whenever I start it from the command line it works totally fine. What I need now is an Executable and therefor I tried to do it with pyinstaller, which analyzes normally automatically which modules have been imported and it works fine with all of the modules except for autoit. The way I import it looks like that:

```
import autoit
```

So I tried to make an executable by following command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile ./rocketupload.py
```

Which gave me this Error (Excuse me, that I have to make a screenshot, but the window was open for a second and closed immediately afterwards, so I was not able to copy and paste it here):
[image: Pyinstaller Error]

I was able to create a functioning exe by copying the autoit dll to the path mentioned in the Error, but that is just a temporary solution, since I want the executable to be running not only on my PC.

I've also tried this one without succes:

```
pyinstaller --hidden-import=autoit --onefile --paths c:\users\semjo\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\autoit\lib .\rocketupload.py
```

So the problem here is that the autoit module does not get copied from pyinstaller so It cannot run the executable as inteded. But I dont know how to solve it, so that the exe can run as intended. Hope you can help me here, tried to find a solution for hours now...

Comment: What I did was to create an spec file and add the file path of autoit_X3.dll in the binary list, it was working like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I had also encountered the same problem and i solved it by implementing the follows:-

1. Re-installed the pyinstaller module using the latest installer available in github i.e. pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip
2. Re-created the executable package by running the command i.e. pyinstaller --hidden-import=selenium --hidden-import=autoit your [python_file.py]
3. Copied the installed module i.e. autoit's folder from my PC's directory (C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages) and pasted it inside the [python_file] folder in dist folder which was generated by pyinstaller.

To test the solution, i re-run the generated .exe file in command prompt. Hope this help.

Comment: This works, but only without "--onefile" flag to create a single executable.

Answer (score 0):

```py
hiddenimports = [ "autoit.init", "autoit.autoit", "autoit.control",
"autoit.process", "autoit.win" ] 
datas = [
    [
        "C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\autoit\\lib\\AutoItX3_x64.dll", 
        "autoit\\lib"
    ]
]
```

https://raveendran.wordpress.com/2012/06/15/how-to-installregister-autoitx3-dll/
Do this two process your issue will resolve. It resolved me.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.