# pyistaller - OSError: Cannot load AutoItX

Tags: python, dll, pyinstaller, autoit

I have python 3.7, pip 20.0.2, pyinstaller 3.6, windows 10.
I have a problem with converting .py to .exe:

at first, I didnt used the `autoit` directory and managed to convert Python file to EXE file via the `pyinstaller` tool, and then run the EXE file.

Then, I added the `autoit` directory and installed it via `PROJECT ITERPETER`.
The python code worked fine running through the PyCharm software IDE (green arrow in Pycharm) I executed the command "pyinstaller --onefile" on the .py file but as soon as I tried to run the EXE-file from dist folder I got a lot of errors in the console when the The common denominator of them all is that in the folder Temp the DLL file is unreadable `"OSError: Cannot load AutoItX from path: C:\Users\Yagel\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI108842\autoit\lib\AutoItX3_x64.dll"`.

I open this folder, and I found out that all the libraries I use in my code **except of the autoit directory** are installed. Of course, now inserting A folder will not help because (from my understanding) pyinstaller takes all these files and groups them to EXE . I was looking for a solution on a network(And particular in StackOverflow) that suggested adding the `--paths c: \ ... autoit` command when I execute pyinstaller command - I added the command and the EXE again with the same errors (of course in a new folder within the TEMP because every run creates a folder there) and again within the folder was not the autoit.
please help me to create the EXE file.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59190771/pyinstaller-oserror-cannot-load-autoitx-from-path/69076292#69076292 sol, for me it resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the way I tried to combine selenium and autoit was wrong.
The right way is to create an EXE file with the aotuit3 software and run the EXE I created from the script using os.system.
The following site has a very detailed guide on how to incorporate it.

https://www.guru99.com/use-autoit-selenium.html